# Where is the Alpha 1 release of Kubuntu 12.04?

Tags: kubuntu, 12.04, testing

I have been looking around, and I can't find any official informational update on the first Alpha release of Kubuntu Precise. Was Alpha 1 released?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple search of Kubuntu+Daily **and** Kubuntu+12.04+Aplha+1 on a random search engine gives you the answer:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/daily-live/current/

It's a daily Image.

Alpha 1 was released 1 Dec. so it's Old and of no use now, daily images are newer. The next Alpha is to be released in Feb.

- Kubuntu 12.04 Alpha 1 – 1/Dic./2011
- Kubuntu 12.04 Alpha 2 – 2/Feb./2012
- Kubuntu 12.04 Beta 1 – 1/Mar./2012
- Kubuntu 12.04 Beta 2 – 22/Mar./2012
- Kubuntu 12.04 RC – 19/Abr./2012
- Kubuntu 12.04 Final Stable – 26/Abr./2012

Comment: The first result that comes when I search "Kubuntu 12.04 Alpha 1" is a link to softpedia that leads me to a 404 when I try to download it.

Comment: Then try the other 10 or so links..

Comment: A few results mention it was released on December 1st, but I couldn't find any official statement or web page (including Kubuntu.org) that mentioned it, which made me think that it wasn't released. None of the results mention daily builds. I new into testing this, so I wasn't aware of daily builds.

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen an official release of Kubuntu 12.04 Alpha yet either nor have I seen an announcement.

FWIW I have been using the daily builds

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/daily/

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is there was no Alpha 1 release of Kubuntu for 12.04 Precise Pangolin. (I understand one of the key developers was in an accident.)

You could have downloaded a daily build, but now the [Alpha 2 release is out](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/precise/alpha-2/).

Answer (score 1):

**Kubuntu release announcements**

Looking the previous release announcements for the Kubuntu:

The Natty started from the Alpha 2: https://wiki.kubuntu.org/NattyNarwhal/Alpha2/Kubuntu

The Oneiric started from the Alpha 3: https://wiki.kubuntu.org/OneiricOcelot/Alpha3/Kubuntu

**Technical Overview**

https://wiki.kubuntu.org/PrecisePangolin/TechnicalOverview

**KDE**

The KDE 4.8 Release Schedule: http://techbase.kde.org/Schedules/KDE4/4.8_Release_Schedule

The KDE 4.8 Feature Plan: http://techbase.kde.org/Schedules/KDE4/4.8_Feature_Plan

**Kubuntu**

The Kubuntu (Ubuntu) Release Schedule : https://wiki.kubuntu.org/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseSchedule

Blueprints for (K)Ubuntu : https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+specs?searchtext=kubuntu

**Discussion**

Ubuntu +1 (Precise Pangolin) : http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=412

Kubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin; Pre-Release Testing : http://www.kubuntuforums.net/forumdisplay.php?145-Pre-Release-Testing